# Existe um gateway de pagamento que aceite créditos de celular?

Tags: integração

Muitas vezes, em games por exemplo, vejo pessoas pagando por recursos extras através de créditos de celular. A UOL possui o Boa Compra, que aceita esse tipo de pagamento, mas não é aberta a desenvolvedores. Alguém saberia me indicar algum gateway que suporte pagamentos assim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma vez que o [PagTotal](http://pagtotal.com.br/) foi descontinuado, só restam as opções tradicionais e extrangeiras:

## Boku

[Boku](http://www.boku.com/) é uma das primeiras plataformas de pagamento por celular e após ao pesquisar em um motor de busca vi que clientes brasileiros (não sei se é o seu foco) conseguem pagar com tal sistema e por isso acredito possa ser viável.

## Zong

[Zong](https://www.zong.com/countries/mobile-payments-brazil) assim como o Boku também foi um dos primeiros sistemas e sei que é suportado no Brasil (se clicar no link acima verá inclusive o *market share* de cada uma das companhias de celular no Brasil.

## Payfone

O [Payfone](http://www.payfone.com/how-it-works.html) entrou no mercado após os dois citados acima e se não me engano era usado bastante para aplicativos de iOS (principalmente iPhone) mas não sei a quantas anda e também não sei dizer se é aceito no Brasil.

**Nota:** usei o Brasil como referência por não saber exatamente para qual mercado está a procurar e como este é o maior país lusófono me pareceu ter mais chances de ser o mesmo.

PS: eu não sei se [essa pergunta é válida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic), acredito que talvez se encaixe em:

> Problemas práticos específicos sobre programação que podem ser respondidos.

mas não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente tenha lhe faltado o termo correto para um pesquisa: **Mobile Payment Gateway**.

Aqui no Brasil não parece ser um meio muito difundido, mas no exterior, principalmente para jogos, muitas vezes é a única solução para quem não dispõe de um cartão de crédito internacional e não tem opções como nosso BoaCompra.

Numa rápida pesquisa você encontra o [PayScape](https://www.payscape.com/mobile-payments.php), o [PayZippy](https://www.payzippy.com/) e o [VeriFone](http://www.verifone.com/solutions-services/payment-gateway/) dentre outros.

No entanto não podemos sugerir qual o melhor para você pois quem sabe as necessidades é você, desenvolvedor e fazendo-o, aqui, esse *stack* poderia ser fechado por passar a se tratar de opiniões.

Answer (score 0):

http://movile.com/payments/faq/

Parece q esse gateway resolve, mas nunca usei e não conheço o sdk

Abraços.